# a cost function that consists of two parts with different second dimension

Tags: python, algorithm, pytorch, loss-function, loss

I have defined a loss function like this:

```
def my_loss(y_recon, y_real, brain_hidden, brain_real):
    loss = torch.mean((y_recon - y_real)**2 + (brain_hidden - brain_real)**2
    return loss
```

`y_recon`'s shape (and `y_real`) is `batch_size*300` and `brain_hidden's` shape (and `brain_real`) is `batch_size*64`

I need to minimize these two both elements. However, this way I get the error

> The size of tensor a (300) must match the size of tensor b (64) at
> non-singleton dimension 1

How can I update the loss function to avoid this error?

Comment: the out put of the loss function is a int right

Comment: The shapes of `(y_recon - y_real)**2` and `(brain_hidden - brain_real)**2` are incompatible, so you can't add them together. Did you mean to write `torch.mean((y_recon - y_real)**2) + torch.mean((brain_hidden - brain_real)**2)` ?

Comment: Generally what myrtlecat says, but also note that if you have non-constant batch size, your loss function will give higher weight to samples that were in smaller batches.